# (SQFLite) Retrieve data from 2 joined tables and convert result query to list

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, dart

I have two models in my app, named Basket and Items. Model Basket contains a list of Items. So it's as follows:

Basket:

```
int id
string name
string imageUrl
List<Items> items
```

Items:

```
string name
string description
int basketId
```

_

My 2 tables:

basket:

```
id
name
imageUrl
```

items:

```
id
name
description
basketId
```

What I want to do is to retrieve all baskets with all its corresponding items and make a List basketList object. I tried to join the tables, but I ended with 4 baskets with null items instead of a basket with 4 items. I'm using SQFLite for flutter.

Answer (score 3):

You were correct to attempt to join the tables.

First, you need to find a way to serialize JSON, as the data returned from [SQLFlite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) is of type `Map<String, dynamic>` which needs to be parsed. In the code snippet, you can assume I have used [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), for which I will use the generated `fromJson` method.

```
Future<List<Item>> getAllBasketsWithCorresponding() async {
  Database db = await openDatabase('your_db_name.db');
  try {
    // Get the records
    List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> dbList = await db.rawQuery('SELECT basket.id, basket.name, basket.imageUrl FROM basket INNER JOIN items ON basket.id = items.basketId');
    dbList.forEach((itemMap) {
      list.add(Item.fromJson(itemMap));
    });
    return list;
  } on Exception {
    return new List<Item>();
  } finally {
    await db.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without joining the tables. First, you get the Maplist of basket from sqflite. Next, as you are converting from Map object to Basket() object, for each basket in the list, you get the list of items and add the list of items to the basket. You can have a helper mapping function to map Map objects from sqflite to your object class.

```
Future<List<Basket>> getBasketList() async{

var basketMapList = await getBasketMapList();
int count = basketMapList.length;

List<Basket> basketList = List<Basket>();

for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

  basketList.add(Basket.fromMapObject(basketMapList[i]));

  // for each basket, add the list of items...
  Future<List<Item>> itemListFuture = getBasketItemList(basketList[i].basketid);
  itemListFuture.then(
        (itemList) {

          basketList[i].items = itemList;

    },
  );
}

return basketList;
```

}

```
// in basket class. Write a similar function for your items object. 
   fromMapObject(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        this.id = map['id'];
        this.name = map['name'];
        this.imageurl = map['imageurl']; 
  }
```

Comment: So your solution to parsing an inner-join, is to query the DB for every related entity? How is the performance of that?

Comment: this should not taken as production way, it's slow and no-effieiency, I mean slow is really slow. very very slow...... it's not a professional way.